# setting the values of arrays in java by using their indexes

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, indexing

How do you initialized an array in java first, and then set values to them by using their indexes? So for example, you make an array in java, and then you want the value of the number 75 index of the array to be set to "seventy five", can you do something like array[75] = "seventy five"?;

```
String[] array;
array[0] = "zero";
array[1] = "one";
array[2] = "two";
```

When I tried the codes below it says unknown class array. What am I doing wrong?

```
String[] array = new String[10];
array[0] = "zero";
```

Comment: first you need to set the size of the array 
String[] array = new String[10];
then you can go ahead and do what you are doing.

Comment: @TimeTrax when I tried this, it says unknown class array when I try to set the value using the indexes.

Comment: 1. Go here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler
2. clear all the text .. select all, delete. 
3. paste the following code =>>>>
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] array = new String[10];
  array[0] = "zero";
  System.out.println(array.length);
  System.out.println(array[0]);
 }
}

4. you will see that i'm right

Comment: If you want to go up to 75 or higher, the above approach may get unwieldy. You may want to refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/ then use a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to point the array reference to an actual array object.

For example,

```
String[] array = new String[3];
```

You can initialize the contents like you're doing.

Or you can initialize them in the array creation expression:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "zero", "one", "two" };
```

You can also the array initializer by itself in the declaration:

```
String[] array = { "zero", "one", "two" };
```

Comment: Does this initialize an array with a size of 3?

Comment: Both of these initialize the array to size 3. The first does because `new String[3]` explicitly asks for that. The second does because the initialization list has three elements.

Comment: Do you know when it's says unknown class array? I'm doing this in android studios.

Comment: @frosty - By any chance are you placing the assignment statements in your class body rather than inside a method? See stackoverflow.com/questions/28448029/…. If so, one solution is to use the array initializers above.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is recommended not to initialize an array like

```
String[] a;
```

Because its actually not an array and you could get Null Pointer Exeption.

I think you'll just have to initialize the array from scratch.

```
String[] array = new String[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four" };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with android studio but your problem is not in array declarations your jvm is not recognizing String class.